# How to use specific RBI file with tc command

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm playing with sorbet and my gem. I create custom `/rbis` folder for RBI file and want to use it in `srb tc` command for checking this library without copying files. Also, I checked the documentation and found nothing.

Any ideas of how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rbi/` instead of `rbis/`. In the latest version of `sorbet`, they dropped the support for `rbis/` (Paul Tarjan just updated the documentation yesterday).

Here is a more detailed instructions:
1. Create a `rbi/` folder at the gem's root director (sibling of `lib/` folder)
2. Put any custom rbi files in there.
3. Profit! `srb tc` works automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but nothing happened:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1147484/60101326-3e582a80-9764-11e9-84eb-7f96a6ea2882.jpg

Comment: It turns out they dropped the support for `rbis/`. It only works with `rbi/` folder now.